# How to Build A Branded Open edX Training Site using bitnami

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitnami, openedx

I'm trying to build branded open edx training site using bitnami but I do not know how can I start and I couldn't understand the documentation so is there is any tutorial, youtube play list or any documentation that can help me ?!!

Answer (score 1):

All required Open edX customization documentations are available on these sites/pages, and I think basic Django experience is a plus.

https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/
https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/edx/configuration/install-default-theme/
https://blog.lawrencemcdaniel.com/open-edx-installation/
https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OpenOPS/pages/60227913/Managing+OpenEdX+Tips+and+Tricks
https://open.edx.org/get-started/get-started-self-managed/

Further, If you specify your struggling points we(Open edX community) may be able to help on those specific items.

Comment: Hi @Isanka Wijerathne thanks for your answer and I visit all links you mention but no one tall about apply instructions on bitnami is that normal

Comment: Basically the main idea is the same for Bitnami also. please specify your struggling points, then it's easy.

Comment: my problem is that i can not understand the documentation so I cant follow it or know what I need to do to build my custom site and bind it by open edx .... sorry Isanka I know it's that it's seem that  I'm confused

Comment: first, bitnami is not my personal preference for the production site. It seems you better start with devstack and understand the basics of the Open edX. ex: in terms of branding main thing is the theme, for that first you need you to develop a theme, then enable it. Check this also. https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/edx/configuration/install-default-theme/